# For loop computations taking so much time

Tags: r, for-loop

With respect to below, question asked previously, now explaining the exact computations to improve the for loop computations.
[For loop & if else working for less data but not working for more data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182385/for-loop-if-else-working-for-less-data-but-not-working-for-more-data)

This is just sample data I have around 2M data. Please help me to perform this computation faster

Final (Input Dataframe):

```
Item   LC  Fiscal.Week   SS   Freq    
 A    MW92   2019-W24    20    1           
 A    OY01   2019-W24    10    0       
 A    RM11   2019-W24    5     1       
 B    WK14   2019-W24    112   0       
 B    RS11   2019-W24    30    1
```

lctolc (Input Dataframe):

```
Item   LC     ToLC
 A    MW92    OY01
 A    OY01    RM11
 B    WK14    RS11
```

Final_v1(Output Dataframe)

```
Item   LC  Fiscal.Week   SS   Freq    SSNew
 A    MW92   2019-W24    20    1        0    
 A    OY01   2019-W24    10    0        0
 A    RM11   2019-W24    5     1        0
 B    WK14   2019-W24    112   0        112
 B    RS11   2019-W24    30    1        0
```

Explanation:

1. First, we need to find the unique items in `Final` dataframe so that code will run item by item

   1. For each item, the code should run in the order mentioned in `lctolc` data frame like for item `A`, `MW92` to `OY02` to `RM11` so first computations will happen at `MW92`, then `OY01`, then `RM11`
   2. For each `Item-LC` pair, it should check in the `Final` dataframe,

      ```
      if we have `Freq == 1` then allocate `SSNew = 0`   else
                  `SSNew = SS`
      ```
2. Now, if `SSNew == 0` then for the remaining `LC`s for that `Item`, i.e. `OY01` & `RM11` so should automatically set `SSNew` for them to `0` irrespective of the value of their `Freq` being `1` or not.
3. Then same computations will begin for `Item` `B`.

Code:

```
df <- as.data.frame(unique(Final$Item))
#New Dataframe with Null values
Final_v1 <- NA
j <- 1
i <- 1

#SS computations
#For 1 to no of rows in df(which is having no of unique items 
for(j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  #copying the data from Final to Final_v1(with charater type)
  Final_v1 <- Final[Final$Item == as.character(df[j,1]),]
  #for 1 to the no of rows in Final_v1
  for(i in 1:nrow(Final_v1)) {


      if(Final_v1[i,4] == '1')
      {
        Final_v1[i,6]=0
      }

      else 
      {
        Final_v1[i,6]=Final_v1[i,3]
      }
     # SSNew <- Final_v1[i,6]

      #Leftover distribution
      LCS <- lctolc$ToLC[Final_v1$Item[i] == lctolc$Item & Final_v1$LC[i] == lctolc$LC]
      inds <- Final_v1$LC %in% LCS    
      if (any(inds))
      {  Final_v1$SS[inds]<- if (Final_v1[i,6] == 0) {Final_v1$SS[inds]==0} else {Final_v1$SS[inds]=Final_v1$SS[inds]}    }
    }



  }

  names(Final_v1)[6] <- "SSNew"
}
```

Comment: @RuiBarradas - Based on the relationship in the dataframe lctolc, we need to proceed. For Item A, we have relationship MW92->OY01->RM11 so first we check the value of Freq at MW92 if it is Freq=1 we assign SSNew=0 for MW92 and also SSNew=0 for OY01 and RM11 also irrespective of their Freq value.
In case, Freq=0 at MW92 then we assign SSNew=SS for MW92, and proceed at OY01 to check Freq at OY01 similarly. So, if we set SSNew=0 then we need to set it across the SSNew=0 for all upcoming LCs for that item as per the lctolc dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Example data frames for testing
Item <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
LC <- c("MW92", "OY01", "RM11", "WK14", "RS11")
ToLC <- c("OY01", "RM11", "RM02", "RS11", "ZM78")
lctolc <- data.frame(Item, LC, ToLC, stringsAsFactors = F)

Item <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
LC <- c("MW92", "OY01", "RM11" ,"LO99", "WK14", "RS11")
SS <- c(20, 10, 5, 99, 112, 30)
Freq <- c(1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1)
final_df_input <- data.frame(Item, LC, SS, Freq, stringsAsFactors = F)


lctolc_merge <- lctolc %>% 
  # splitting df by Item
  dplyr::group_split(Item) %>% 
  # add a row for each df
  purrr::map(.,dplyr::add_row) %>% 
  # binding everything back together
  do.call(bind_rows, .) %>% 
  # replacing the NA's with the Item
  dplyr::mutate(
    Item = case_when(
      is.na(Item) ~ lag(Item),
      TRUE~ Item)) %>% 
  # grouping df
  dplyr::group_by(Item) %>% 
  # creating the rank for each LC
  # All LC's are put into LC_merge
  dplyr::mutate(rank = row_number(),
                LC_merge = case_when(
                  rank == 1 ~ LC,
                  TRUE ~ lag(ToLC)))

# merging lctolc with final Input df
final_df_input %>% 
  # merging df by LC and Item
  dplyr::left_join(., lctolc_merge, 
                   by = c("LC" = "LC_merge", "Item" = "Item")) %>% 
  # replacing NA's 
  dplyr::group_by(Item) %>% 
  # creating SSNew as before
  dplyr::mutate(min_row = which.min(Freq),
                first_row = case_when(
                  min_row == rank & Freq == 0 ~ min_row),
                first_0 = case_when(
                  any(which.min(first_row)) ~ min_row,
                  TRUE ~ 0L),
                SSNew = case_when(
                  is.na(rank) & Freq == 0 ~ 0,
                  rank >= first_0 & first_0 != 0 ~ 0,
                  TRUE ~ SS)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(Item, LC, SS, Freq, rank, min_row, first_0, SSNew)
```

Result:

```
  Item  LC       SS  Freq  rank min_row first_0 SSNew
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <int>   <int> <dbl>
1 A     MW92     20     1     1       2       2    20
2 A     OY01     10     0     2       2       2     0
3 A     RM11      5     1     3       2       2     0
4 A     LO99     99     2    NA       2       2    99
5 B     WK14    112     0     1       1       1     0
6 B     RS11     30     1     2       1       1     0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197015/discussion-on-answer-by-m-schumacher-for-loop-computations-taking-so-much-time).

Comment: I tried replacing Freq==0 with Freq==1, but it doesn't seems to be working. It makes everything 0 even where there is Freq==0. Please help

Comment: @M. Schumacher - Code is running for more than 30mins then also no output and tried replacing Freq==0 with Freq==1, but it doesn't seems to be working. It makes everything 0 even where there is Freq==0. Please help

Answer (score 2):

This base R solution follows the `lctolc` table but I don't know if it's faster.

```
ssNew <- function(DF, LC2LC){
  f <- function(df1, lc2lc){
    inx <- which(df1[['LC']] %in% unique(unlist(lc2lc)))
    for(i in inx){
      if(df1$Freq[i] == 1) break
      df1$SSnew[i] <- df1$SS[i]
    }
    df1
  }
  g <- function(df1){
    inx <- seq_len(nrow(df1))
    for(i in inx){
      if(df1$Freq[i] == 1) break
      df1$SSnew[i] <- df1$SS[i]
    }
    df1
  }
  DF[['SSnew']] <- 0
  sp1 <- split(DF, DF[['Item']])
  sp2 <- split(LC2LC, LC2LC[['Item']])
  DFItem <- unique(DF[['Item']])
  nms <- intersect(DFItem, LC2LC[['Item']])
  res <- lapply(DFItem, function(i) {
    if(i %in% nms){
      f(sp1[[i]], sp2[[i]])
    }else{
      g(sp1[[i]])
    }
  })
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

Final_v1 <- ssNew(Final, lctolc)

Final_v1
#  Item   LC Fiscal.Week  SS Freq SSnew
#1    A MW92    2019-W24  20    1     0
#2    A OY01    2019-W24  10    0     0
#3    A RM11    2019-W24   5    1     0
#4    B WK14    2019-W24 112    0   112
#5    B RS11    2019-W24  30    1     0
```

Comment: Also, I am getting this error:  Error in sp2[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @AnshulSaravgi `DF` and `df1` are just argument names, in the functions I don't use the real names, the functions process data sets that only exist inside them. As for the error, is it occurring with other data? With the posted example I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Yes, error is occuring with other data when I processed 80k data.
SO, I don't need to change the argument names right I should use DF and df1?

Comment: @AnshulSaravgi No, there is no need to correct those names, it was a bug in the function. And I have corrected the bug, I believe it now works as expected.

Comment: @AnshulSaravgi Note that the error is only possible if there are items in `Final` not present in `lctolc`. What do you want to do with those items? Like this the function **does not** process them, their `SSnew` will be set to zero.

Comment: Yes, now it is working fine. But it is taking 25-30 mins for 80k data. Can we make it more fast?

Comment: Also, in Final dataframe I have 80k records, in lctolc 57k records but Final_v1 is having only 53k records. Why is it so, it should have 80k records only

Comment: If I have an Item present in Final dataframe, but it is not there in lctolc dataframe then also it should come in Final_v1 dataframe with checking only the Freq condition

Comment: Please help me here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196987/discussion-between-anshul-saravgi-and-rui-barradas).

Comment: Can you please help me out with the following doubts

Comment: For items in Final not present in lctolc, their SSNew should be just based on the condition of Freq = 0 or 1. Please help here

Comment: Doe is not working as per the functionality, I have relationship like OY->MW.
If MW is coming first in the Final dataframe and it is not having Freq=1 then it is giving value of SS but after that when it comes to OY which has Freq=1 then it is making Oy=0 but not MW. Ideally, it should make MW also as 0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` solution which relies on a join.

```
Final <- fread('Item   LC  Fiscal.Week   SS   Freq    
 A    MW92   2019-W24    20    1           
 A    OY01   2019-W24    10    0       
 A    RM11   2019-W24    5     1       
 B    WK14   2019-W24    112   0       
 B    RS11   2019-W24    30    1')

lctolc <- fread(
  'Item   LC     ToLC
 A    MW92    OY01
  A    OY01    RM11
  B    WK14    RS11')
#converting to data.table if reading from xlsx
setDT(Final)
setDT(lctolc)

#initializing
Final[, ToLC := shift(LC, 1, type = 'lead')]
Final[, SSNew := 0L]

# update join
Final[lctolc
      ,on = .(Item, LC, ToLC)
      , SSNew := as.integer(SS)*!Freq] #coerces Freq to logical. If freq is more than 1, it wouldn't work

#condition that if first of each group is 0, then everything is 0.
Final[, SSNew_First := first(SSNew), by = 'Item']
Final[SSNew_First == 0, SSNew := 0]

#clean up data.table by removing unneeded columns
Final[, `:=` (SSNew_First = NULL, ToLC = NULL)]

#print
Final

   Item   LC Fiscal.Week  SS Freq SSNew
1:    A MW92    2019-W24  20    1     0
2:    A OY01    2019-W24  10    0     0
3:    A RM11    2019-W24   5    1     0
4:    B WK14    2019-W24 112    0   112
5:    B RS11    2019-W24  30    1     0
```

Comment: How can we do this for a dataframe which I am loading via xlsx

Comment: Do ```setDT(Final)``` and the same thing for your other data.frame

Comment: See edit - right after the ```fread()``` statements I added it to the code. Did it work?